# Unexpected Token Var

Tags: javascript

**I have a error unexpected token var. I searched but no answer to my question. My code where there is error:**
NOTE: This not the full code and a part where error is. Its at line 2.

```
function firstPart() {
    var chin = document.getElementById('dialog');
    var name = document.getElementById('textf').value;
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not missing the closing curly brace- }

Comment: Please close the function {}

Comment: Are you doing any AJAX calls?

Comment: Dudes half code. Full code has bracket closed. 3@ No. I don't know AJAX

Comment: Split your line into: `function firstPart() {` and `var chin = document.getElementById('dialog');` and `var name = document.getElementById('textf').value;` and see which line gives the error.

Comment: var secondPart = function () {
};
dcr both works. but creates new error. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input (Another function)

Comment: Could you provide complete code along with the html markup for the 'dialog and 'textf' element. Maybe that could give us some cues.

Comment: -1 because @Derek 朕會功夫 was being helpful.

Comment: only for textf <input type="text" style = "width: 94em;" id = "textf">

Comment: Could you create a fiddle of your complete code? I reckon there may be another script that could be preventing the 'textf' element from being rendered.

Comment: dare you guyz if you leak it or do something to it. http://jsfiddle.net/8zuLW/

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, the syntax for a function is:

```
function functionName() {
//lines of code
}
```

The code that you have provided here is missing the the closing curly brace (}).

Add the closing curly brace and see what happens.

As for your code itself, there is nothing wrong with it.

It works correctly when the closing curly brace is added to it.

You can see that here: http://jsfiddle.net/UaySK/1/

Hope this helps.

Comment: OP mentioned the "full code has bracket closed."

Comment: not working , same error

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 OP mentioned that in a comment after I had answered here.

Comment: ^ and thatt was half code. That means Derek doesn't read what i asked fully-_- See the NOTE please.

Comment: @UnknoWnMember - That means you didn't read what I commented fully-_- I explicitly said this is only part of your whole code and there indeed is a closing bracket.